# qTranslate with my own theme and settings

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options, plugin-qtranslate

Basically I have my own theme and my own settings page. In that settings page I have a textfield which contains a Welcome Text to show at the top of the website.

Now, I want this theme to works with qTranslate. To make the content of this textfield multi-language, it would be easy just to let the user add the qTranslate tags by himself within it.

However, internally, while I'm rendering the Welcome Text, which function of qTranslate should I call? It would be perfect if I could pass to it only the text (with the tags) in argument, and depending on the current language qTranslate would give me back the right part of the text.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9

You can use `_e();` function to echo your variable and `__();` to return your variable. Qtranslate hooks into these functions and translates following your input.

Comment: Excellent, that was easy and exactly what I was looking for. I didn't look much into that issue it seems. Thanks :)